# Restoring from git when local directory is gone

Tags: git, restore, pull

Ok this is going to get complicated:

My `.git` directory is in a different directory than the source files. You can actually do that with:

```
/usr/local/bin/git --git-dir /www/git/site/ --work-tree=. commit -a
```

(when you're in the directory of the source files. Unconventional, but that's how we do it, and it's supported).

The directory with the source files has been deleted.

But the `.git` repository hasn't, because it's in a separate directory. I can see it, I know where it is.

How do I restore everything from our latest commit into a new directory? I tried this in a new directory:

```
/usr/local/bin/git --git-dir /www/git/site/ --work-tree=. pull
```

gives:

> fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
>   remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

(fyi there's no remote server, this is all local)

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.  I never knew it was possible to work with the .git directory in a different location.  I think this can come in handy in some very interesting ways.

Answer (score 1):

After creating a new directory, change into that directory.  Then, you can restore the entire tree with the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/git --git-dir /www/git/site/ --work-tree=. reset --hard
```

if that doesnt work, try adding `.git` to the location:

```
/usr/local/bin/git --git-dir /www/git/site/.git/ --work-tree=. reset --hard
```